# fill a layer with a unique color in cocos2d-js

Tags: cocos2d-js

I can't find a way to fill a layer with a unique color in cocos2d-js like we do in cocos2d-x.

If you have done it, please share how.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create a `cc.LayerColor` instance with a specific color.  The color you provided will fill in the whole layer.

eg. Create a red solid colored layer:

```
 var winSize = cc.winSize;
 var colorLayer = new cc.LayerColor(cc.color(255,0,0), 200,200);
 colorLayer.setPosition(cc.p(100,100));
 this.addChild(colorLayer);
```